# Cannot use the copy function

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, copy

What is wrong with `copy` (which is a generic function), here? I cannot run the code.

```
vector<int> a(10, 2);
vector<int> b(a.size());

auto ret = copy(a.begin(), a.end(), b);

for (auto i : b) cout << i << endl;
```

Here's the output after compiling:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Project1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  MainEx.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2176): error C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(2157) : see declaration of 'std::_Copy_impl'
1>          c:\users\amin\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\project1\project1\mainex.cpp(40) : see reference to function template instantiation '_OutIt std::copy<std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>,std::vector<_Ty>>(_InIt,_InIt,_OutIt)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _OutIt=std::vector<int>,
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>,
1>              _Ty=int,
1>              _InIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<int>>>
1>          ]
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[std::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) 3rd parameter is an iterator, pass `b.begin()` instead:

```
 #include <iterator>
 ...

 auto ret = std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
```

The better way is to construct `b` from `a`, in this case, compiler knows to allocate all needed memory at once and construct elements from `a`:

```
 vector<int> b(a.begin(), a.end());
```

or

```
 std::vector<int> b = a;
```

Comment: +1 for the second part, but he doesn't need back_inserter here.

Comment: or can use `vector<int> b{a.begin(), a.end()};` with C++11

Comment: agree both, I was trying to avoid insert to begin() which will reallocate elements.

Comment: The thing is, the use of `std::back_inserter` does something different to the other alternatives you state.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass an iterator, and you are passing an `std::vector<int>`. In your case, you should pass `b.begin()`:

```
auto ret = copy(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
//                                    ^^^^^^^
```

Of course, the simple way to achieve the same result would be

```
vector<int> b = a;
```

Answer (score 3):

`auto ret = copy(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());`

should do the job.

all arguments of `std::copy` need to be iterators.

Answer (score 2):

You have to copy to `b.begin()` as the third argument to `copy` is an iterator, not a container.

```
auto ret = copy(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
```